# Why did Klingons attack the medical ship in "All Good Things..."?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng

In the middle of [the final episode of *Star Trek: The Next Generation*](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/All_Good_Things..._%28episode%29), we learn that

> in the future, the Klingons have defeated the Romulans, they're no longer at peace with Federation and they're only allowing medical ships to pass through the sector previously known as Neutral Zone.

If that's so, then why did they attack a medical ship? A ship that has no firepower to match any of the attackers and that was declaring a pure medical mission? Why didn't they respond to any hails or even the declaration of surrender?

What is the reason the Klingons destroyed a medical, defenceless, surrendering ship? Is this honorable at all?

It is clearly said, previously in this episode, that the situation between Klingon and the Federation is *delicate*. It is far from a state of war, and even during war you usually don't destroy a medical ship that declares surrender and is no threat at all for you.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Klingons are never far from war declaration.

Comment: No, they are not. But, in the same time, they value honor as something the most important in their lives. And -- I must repeat myself -- even the most stupid Klingon should not find anything famous or honorable in destroying defenseless, surrounding medical ship. Who could glory the coward's destroyer?

Answer (score 5):

It was a medical ship, but it wasn’t actually on a medical mission. It was entering the former Romulan-Federation neutral zone, without the apparently-necessary permission of the Klingon Empire. That’s at least suspicious behaviour on the part of the Federation.

Quite frankly, they didn’t have a leg to stand on.

Comment: And even it being unarmed and non-military, it's so only in appearance, as far as Klingons are concerned. Also, victory is a victory when in the service of the Empire.

Comment: @AcePL: tonight we will bathe in the blood of paediatricians!

Comment: Your answer may answer the question from logic point of view, but definitely does not answer it from the episode (canon, in-universe) point of view. As far as I'm concerned: (1) Klingons had no knowledge, that ship is going to investigate anything, they have declared medical mission. (2) Worf (as an ambassador) had agreed on entering that part of space, assuming he agreed that with the High Council or at least reported that fact somewhere (can't believe in Worf making such decisions alone). To summary, IMHO: Klingons had absolutely no reasons to attack that ship.

Comment: @AcePL Paul's comment is perfect explanation here. Are you really, really sure that honorable and proud Klingons would ever cherish or glorify someone, who killed a defenseless, surrendering coward? Because that's how this medical ship could look from Klingons' point of view. Everything I learnt about them from watching entire ST:TNG tells me, that not. They're not proud of killing someone in this conditions.

Comment: Never said it would be honourable and/or something to be proud of. You're trying to put Klingon mindset into western (or, to be precise: Roman-Christian) frames. Case in point: Bushido - it's all about honor, glory and pride in the service to the Emperor. And yet, they were worse than Germans during WWII (worse, because for them it was personal, Germans did it as a matter of - almost - technological process): killing POWs, Death March etc. In other words - there's no honor in killing coward, but he had to be put down (pun intended). It's an honor TO the coward: be killed by warrior in battle.

Comment: @trejder: reading [the plot summary on Memory Alpha](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/All_Good_Things..._%28episode%29#Act_Six), it seems that Worf accompanies them, but is not able to get them permission to enter that area of space. Riker riles Worf into agreeing by saying that the Worf he knew wouldn’t worry about regulations. Likewise, I don’t think Klingons in general in TNG require substantial evidence of hostile intent or notable strength before attacking an enemy.

Comment: There might not be much honour in destroying the Pasteur, but I don’t think there would be dishonour. It’s a Federation ship, and it’s in the wrong part of space. Unless there’s a great reason *not* to attack it, it’s going down.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite: Exactly. And this is commonly known as duty.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite Are your comments referring only to the "future" timeline presented in this episode or to general Klingons attitude in entire serie? In first case I agree with your explanation. In second case (where Klingons are somewhat allies to Federation) such behavior would sound like terrible misunderstanding of "ally" definition. Am I right?

Comment: @trejer: bits of both. “It’s a Federation ship, and it’s in the wrong part of space” — that’s just the future timeline. “I don’t think Klingons in general in TNG require substantial evidence of hostile intent or notable strength before attacking an enemy” — the entire series.

Comment: @trejder: like if a ship looks like an enemy ship on the face of it, I don’t think a Klingon would say “Wait though, let’s do a bit more research so that we’re sure this is an enemy.” They’d unsheathe the Bat’leth (metaphorically speaking) and have at it.